# Facebook like button not works on android API 23

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-like

I've tested on Samsung A3 (it has installed latets version of facebook app, maybe problem here), and tested on Cubolt X-16 (it hasn't installed facebook app). On Samsung A3 likeview not works but shows how many people like of this post but i can't like. On Cubolt X-16 works as charm. I've added onErrorListener but any errors occurred.

```
likeView.setObjectIdAndType(
        "https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers",
        LikeView.ObjectType.PAGE
);
```

Facebook SDK is 4.20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the phone Cubolt X-16 account of facebook is mine, and on the A3 another accaunt.
The problem was that facebook not allows to all users like in your app while you do not submit app for approval.
For allow to all users liking in your program, you must submit for approval your application at first. After review of your app it will be possible to like for any users in your app.